# Objective C, scrolling menu thumbnail

Tags: iphone

how to make menu like this on iPad or iPhone application

[image]

can anyone help me ?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

- Set the backgroundView's alpha to 0.5.
- Create A UIScrollView
- Add Images to the scrollView
- Add a transform to the images as the images are scrolled through.

Or

- Download Coverflow: http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/tapku-coverflow and implement it.